# URL Rewrite regex, can't seem to get it to not force the include of www.'s

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I've got the Hellicon Tech URL rewrite ISAPI filter on my server. I've got a global file that dictates the settings across the server with the following.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} (on)?
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(?!www\.)(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)
RewriteRule .? http(?%1s)://www.%2%3 [R=301,L]
```

Basically it forces any request coming to the site to apply a "www." to prefix the URL that's being requested.

I've created a specific set of rules for a site on my server, but each time I attempt to modify the pattern to not force the www.'s it either breaks simply doesn't work.

I've narrowed this down to being specifically around the regular expressions, however I cant' seem to get it right.

Any suggestions on making this work would be greatly appreciated, still wanting to keep the https if the domain is requiring it, but trying to eliminate the www. prefix wont seem to work.

Comment: Are you trying to make www optional or do you want to force people to use the non-www domain?

Comment: trying to force the use of non www. on specific domains with a config done on a per site basis. We have a global set of rules for all sites, but are trying to make the local config of a website have the ability to overwrite it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test this with Hellicon's ISAPI, but have you tried something simpler?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}:s (on:(s)|off:s)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http%2://www.%{HTTP:Host}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

remember to clear your browser's cache before testing, the 301 redirect is permanent and your browser will cache the redirected target.